# Add new media uploader at frontend for wp 3.5+

Tags: uploads, media-library, front-end, user-access

I create a form for user to submit content from the frontend. The only problem is I don't know how to handler the image upload.

So, I want to know how to use the WP media uploader in the frontend. The media uploader should be appeared like in the 'wp-admin/media-new.php'. 
I don't want the pop up version of the uploader, as it seen in post/page page. Because it has other feature that I don't want user to use, such as 'Media Library', 'Create gallery', 'Set Featured Image' etc.

Is there any tutorial or documentation on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function add_media_upload_scripts() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
         return;
       }
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_media_upload_scripts');
```

This will cause the the media upload files to load on your front end pages. If you would like to load them only on one specific page where they will be needed, you can wrap `wp_enqueue_media()` in an `is_page()` statement to check to see if the page being displayed is the specific page you need.

After that, you can follow the instructions in this tutorial: http://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/

Comment: Okay, I will try this and get back to you if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

the Ajax calls for [/wp-admin/media-upload.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/media-upload.php) so there is good position to start.

it calls the action: "media_upload_$type", for exemple media_upload_image from [/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L2512](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L2512)

that is connected to the function [wp_media_upload_handler()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L578)

You can dig deeper from there. ( I need som sleep now :-) )

Comment: Your suggestion seem need a lot of time for me to figure out how to apply it. However, I found out that wp is come with plupload plugin. So I will dig into this first. Your Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [results](https://www.google.com/#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=dbfdf7e246ea3597&q=Media+uploader+on+front+end+WordPress) from a Google search I did and here is a plugin that will allow you to upload from the frontend of your site [Frontend Uploader](http://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/)

That should get you started in a good direction as far as tutorials that be available.

Good luck

Comment: No, I don't want the third party plugin. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.